# dhclient and dhcpcd the real difference

Tags: dhcp

I can't figure out the difference from just the man pages. I can see what is a daemon and one is a client, but what does that mean practically when using the commands?  Also what is the difference between the client and daemon in this case, not just the terms (client and daemon) but functionally wise? **EDIT: How are the tasks divided, if the client updates the information on the client, what is the purpose of the daemon. I'm talking about the client daemon in this case dhcpcd not dhcpd. Both come installed by default with some versions of Linux and seem to share the duties of the dhcp client.**

> NAME dhcpcd - DHCP client daemon

```
Name
dhclient - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol Client
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ISC provides dhclient, and as such, it serves as sort of a reference. The more lightweight dhcpcd is somewhat more up to date. Both dhcpcd and dhclient are fully capable DHCP client daemons.  Dhclient is not a "one-time" utility:

**man dhclient**

> -w     Continue  running  even  if  no  broadcast interfaces were found.
>                 Normally DHCP client will exit if it isn't able to  identify  any
>                 network  interfaces  to configure. (...)

That is more like the default behavior of dhcpcd.

---

DHCP has been kind of a moving target, with various vendors (Microsoft in particular) introducing various deviations from the standard.

Answer (score 5):

One new looming difference is that one has reached End Of Maintenance!

https://www.isc.org/blogs/dhcp-client-relay-eom/

Comment: They killed the server too, announcement:  https://www.isc.org/blogs/isc-dhcp-eol/

Answer (score 3):

Debian offers a `dhcpcd` package.  The package description reads as follows:

`Simple configuration: supports executions of a script when the IP address changes.`

`dhclient` is usually used in this fashion:
`dhclient -v eth0` or similar - what will happen is that it will send a broadcast out of `eth0`, and if a DHCP server replies, it will apply information given to `eth0`.  It will then exit.  It will not monitor the interface thereafter.  I haven't used `dhcpcd` but I presume that is its purpose.

You would use `dhclient` if things are messed up and you wanted to fetch a fresh IP from a DHCP server manually.  Good tool to have and that is why many distros include it I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like ISC dhclient is not a one-shot client. Its manpage, [man dhclient(8)](https://kb.isc.org/docs/isc-dhcp-44-manual-pages-dhclient) says:

```
Normally the DHCP client will run in the foreground until is has
configured an interface at which time it will revert to running in
the background.
```

You can use `-1` flag to ask dhclient to try only once to get an IP and then exit on fail. From man page:

```
The -1 flag cause dhclient to try once to get a lease.  If it 
fails, dhclient exits with exit code two.
```